# How to use a C CGI program to send the user to a URL at the end of the program

Tags: html, c, cgi

I have a CGI program in C and it is suppose to accept input from HTML form tag, which it can do but then after it gets the data from the form tag it will check if user credentials is valid. After it is validated, how would I use the CGI to send me to another webpage.

I have tried just printing out the html which works as well but doesn't seem like the right way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CGI doesn't care that your program is written in C or anything else; the method for redirecting is the same.  Set the status code to "302" (or 303), and include a `Location` header specifying the new webpage.

The simplest version of the code would be something like:

```
fprintf(stdout,"%d %s\r\n",302,"Redirect");
fprintf(stdout,"%s: %s\r\n","Location","/newpage");
```